# comparing values in common columns of two diferrent tables and display the difference

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have two tables `USER` and `USER_BAL`. `USER _ID` is primary key of `USER` table and foreign key of `USER_BAL` table. I need to compare the `USER_ID` column of both table in order to make sure that any value in `USER_BAL.USER_ID` has a matching value in `USER.USER_ID`. I also need to output the left out ones.

Comment: i am a newbie in sql. pls help me.. pls...

Comment: Welcome to SO. What have you tried? Post some working queries, does not matter if the result is incorrect, is a starting point and maybe you are not far from the solution. Also showing your table schemas will get you some answers. And last but not least, if possible, post some test data. You can use [SQL Fiddle online tool](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3) to provide all this information.

Comment: what do u mean by compare?

Comment: And also, your tags states you are using SQL SERVER and PL/SQL. It should be either one or the other.

Comment: What is the reason to tag it with PL/SQL? Are you doing this in a stored procedure?

Answer (score 1):

The following will give you all the users with an entry in User_Bal but not in User:

```
SELECT DISTINCT User_Bal.UserID
From User_Bal
Where User_Bal.UserID NOT IN
(
   SELECT User.UserID
   FROM USER
)
```

Ivan's answer is a good starting point if you need to get UserIDs in User but not in User_Bal AND UserIDs in User_Bal but not in User.

However, the results will depend on your DB schema.  Is User to User_Bal a one-to-one or one-to-many relationship?

If one-to-one then you should change your schema to make UserID both a FK and PK of the User_Bal table.  If one-to-many then Ivan's answer will return multiple rows for the same UserID.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

This query give the userid which is exists into user table.

```
SELECT USER_BAL.USER_ID 
FROM USER_BAL 
WHERE EXISTS (
                SELECT USER.USER_ID 
                FROM USER 
                WHERE USER.USER_ID = USER_BAL.USER_ID
             )
```

This query give the userid which is not exists into user table

```
SELECT USER_BAL.USER_ID 
FROM USER_BAL 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
                    SELECT USER.USER_ID 
                    FROM USER 
                    WHERE USER.USER_ID = USER_BAL.USER_ID
                 )
```